# How do I build a GNU Global tags file with files not in the root directory?

Tags: c++, vim, gnu-global

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
~/sourcecode1/myproject
~/sourcecode2/myproject
```

I want to use gtags in vim to find calls to functions declared in both the `sourcecode1` and `sourcecode2` trees, with calls coming from either of those trees (e.g. a function defined in `~/sourcecode1/myproject/somefile.cpp` might call a function declared in `~/sourcecode2/myproject/someotherfile.hpp`). I **do not** want to tag any other folders other than the *myproject* folders.

. How do I build my tags files to achieve this? Currently I've just been running gtags within one of the two directories, and then foregoing gtags functionality when looking through files in the other directory.

Surely there's a better way!

Also, not sure if this belongs in SU.

Answer (score 1):

Although I may not understand your question, 
is that you are asking this?

```
$ find */myproject -type f -print >gtags.files
$ gtags
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#Applied-usage (which gives a similar solution, but saves the file list under /tmp) and http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html#gtags (or `$ man gtags`).